# How to change device config in loaded tensorflow model

Tags: java, tensorflow

Let's say I train my model on a given configuration has GPUs than I would like to use this model for prediction so I save it using the model builder (prediction method signature is constructed). Than I's like to use this model to do prediction in a java environment abut that has no GPU available and I would like to do some tuning on the operation to parallelize them on multiple CPUs.

How can I achieve this with the java api? 
I found if I build new operation I can assign device to it with setDevice, but how can I change the existing operation cam from the loaded model? Is it possible? Is it possible with the java api?

Or what's the correct way to overcome on such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to clear the devices when exporting the model from your Python training process. This would amount to setting [`clear_devices=True`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder#add_meta_graph) when using the `SavedModelBuilder`.

Regarding "some tuning on the operation to parallelize them on multiple CPUs" - the TensorFlow runtime underlying the Java API should do that automatically for you - scheduling operations in parallel if possible and using multiple threads for individual operations when possible.

If you really want to control the configuration specified by the [`ConfigProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L185), you can construct the appropriate proto using the the [ConfigProto.Builder Java class](http://static.javadoc.io/org.tensorflow/proto/1.2.0/org/tensorflow/framework/ConfigProto.Builder.html) ([org.tensorflow:proto](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.tensorflow%22%20AND%20a%3A%22proto%22) maven package), serialize it and provide it to the `Session` constructor, using something like this:

```
ConfigProto config = ConfigProto.newBuilder()
  .setInterOpParallelismThreads(1)
  .build();
try (Session sess = new Session(graph, config.toByteArray())) {
  System.out.println("Created Session with: " + config.toString());
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I have to set at least the intra_op_parallelism_threads correctly isn't it? By default it's 2 and I can go up the the number of cores I have available!?

Comment: I edited the answer to include how to use `ConfigProto`. However, note that by default it is 0, not 2, which [means that it will pick an appropriate number](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L194).

(Note that config.proto is a protocol-buffer schema description, so the "= 2" there is the tag given to the field of the message, not the default value)